What is the scatter plot of the numbers that i will provide
X.    Y
780 90
350 87
920 95
1000    96
450 88
300 85
640 91
520 89
890 94
720 93
200 86
980 97
600 90
430 86
760 92
910 94
370 87
550 89
850 95
250 85
A scatter plot picture please help me with this i will be waiting for the answer

hi, you're going to get downvoted for this, so quickly add details on what kind of plot, and what programming method you tried to use to generate it

Go to the Help center and get acquainted with the standards we expect of a question. You haven't even included what language you want this done in.


here the python code...
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data points
X = [780, 350, 920, 1000, 450, 300, 640, 520, 890, 720, 200, 980, 600, 430, 760, 910, 370, 550, 850, 250]
Y = [90, 87, 95, 96, 88, 85, 91, 89, 94, 93, 86, 97, 90, 86, 92, 94, 87, 89, 95, 85]

# Create scatter plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue')
plt.title('Scatter Plot of X vs Y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

